# Run App even user kills the app in IOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, background, task, kill

I want to make an IOS app in which I want to run the app even the user has killed the app from the main thread. For example a Reminder or Alarm Clock app in which even it is not running but still we get the alerts. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this task in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run if you have been killed. That is what it means to be killed. The user is in charge of what is running - not you.

But you can schedule a UILocalNotification so that the system will put up an alarm alert for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule local notifications (UILocalNotification) to popup in the future.  The notifications can be repeating or one-shot.

If the user taps on the notification (or optional custom actions), the app will be restarted.   If not, there is no way to keep your app running long term.

I have also read that an app can remain running in the background by playing a repeating silent audio file, but probably not Apple approved.